# How to integrate RestKit Framework (restkit.org) with xCode 4?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, restkit

I followed the instructions on the [github](https://github.com/twotoasters/RestKit) page but something is wrong (most certainly is me: P) but, Do you know about any good tutorial for integrate / use in Xcode4 RestKit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Download the latest version from this Link http://restkit.org/

and extract the zip folder and you will find a ReadMe.md file which explains you steps to install for Xcode 4.x as shown below

### Xcode 4.x (Git Submodule)

1. Add the submodule: `git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git RestKit`
2. Open the project you wish to add RestKit to in Xcode.
3. Focus your project and select the "View" menu > "Navigators" > "Project" to bring the project file list into view.
4. Drag the RestKit.xcodeproj file from the Finder and drop it on your "".xcodeproj.
5. Click on your project's name in the sidebar on the left to open the project settings view in the right pane of the window.
6. In the middle pane you will see **PROJECT** and **TARGETS** headers for your project. Click on your project name, then select **Build Settings** along the top to open the Build Settings editor for your entire project.
7. Find the **Header Search Paths** setting. Double click and add a new entry. Add a search path to the `"$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build"` directory you have added to your project. **DO NOT** check the `Recursive` checkbox.
8. Find the **Library Search Paths** setting. Double click and add a new entry. Add a search path to the `"$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build/$(BUILD_STYLE)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)"` directory you have added to your project.
   **NOTE**: This is only necessary if you are **NOT** using DerivedData.
9. Find the **Other Linker Flags** entry and double click it. Use the **+** button to add a new entry and enter `-ObjC -all_load`. Dismiss the editor with the **Done** button.
10. Locate the target you wish to add RestKit to in the **TARGETS** list in the middle of the editor pane. Select it to open the target settings editor in the right pane of the window.
11. Click the **Build Phases** tab along the top of the window to open the Build Phases editor.
12. Click the disclosure triangles next to the **Target Dependencies** and **Link Binary with Libraries** items.
13. In the **Target Dependencies** section, click the **+** button to open the Target selection sheet. Click on the **RestKit** aggregate target (it will have the bulls-eye icon) and click the **Add** button to create a dependency.
14. In the **Link Binary with Libraries** section, click the **+** button to open the Library selection sheet. Here we need to instruct the target to link against all the required RestKit libraries and several system libraries. Select each of the following items (one at a time or while holding down the Command key to select all of them at once) and then click the **Add** button:

    - **libRestKitCoreData.a** - Optional. Only necessary if you are using Core Data.
    - **libRestKitJSONParserJSONKit.a**
    - **libRestKitNetwork.a**
    - **libRestKitObjectMapping.a**
    - **libRestKitSupport.a**
    - **CFNetwork.framework**
    - **CoreData.framework** - Optional. Only necessary if you are using Core Data
    - **MobileCoreServices.framework**
    - **SystemConfiguration.framework**
    - **libxml2.dylib** - Optional. Only necessary if you are mapping from XML payloads and link libRestKitXMLParserLibxml.a into your app.
15. Verify that all of the libraries are showing up in the **Link Binary with Libraries** section before continuing.

Congratulations, you are now done adding RestKit into your Xcode 4 based project!

You now only need to add includes for the RestKit libraries at the appropriate places in your application. The relevant includes are:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
// And if you are using Core Data...
#import <RestKit/CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Comment: stuck on step 1 :( how do you 'add a submodule'?

Comment: Ignore step 1 if you have downloaded the latest version from this Link http://restkit.org/, extract it and follow from step2

Answer (score 3):

I found this tutorial very useful to make it work on xCode 4.0.

http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/

Answer (score 2):

I did my build following this steeps https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x and guoleii is right. But  I needed to change the owner directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this threads from RestKit's Google Group?

[link 1](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/29d0b7fcf1231e18)
[link 2](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/2bbc8074c508e894/4e621c000449ad07?#4e621c000449ad07)

Try searching there. But for now, there seems to be A LOT of issues with RestKit and Xcode 4, there's even a YouTube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_hr_wAF8X8&feature=related) showing the problems (none showing a how-to).

Comment: Thanks Federico I just read the links and seems you are right, so I will wait, for now :S

Answer (score 0):

did you build RestKit according to the wiki page "Installing RestKit in Xcode 4.x" on github.com/RestKit? i think there is a little mistake. here is my solution: 1. in "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries", delete the RestKit.framework and add Security.frameWork 2. build again

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install RestKit on a newly created Xcode 5 iOS 7.0 project. I tried downloading the project and following the steps above, but i was missing most of the content with in the RestKit/Vendor folder. After doing a bit of research i did the submodule tactic and that got me all of the information from those folders.

From the command prompt change directory into your project folder, for me it was

```
$ cd Documents/Projects/NewlyCreatedApp
```

From there you should run this command if you have no git repository
Note: you must download git to install this, if you have not already

```
$ git init
```

after that you must run these commands to download restkit into your project folder

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After that, you should go up to Nakkeeran's answer above and start from step 2, to set up the process. In step 7 you will be asked to add "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build" to your header search paths, but upon closer inspection the RestKit framework no longer has the build folder so you should change that to "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Code" to fit the current version of Rest Kit

I hope this helps, and here is a link to the submodule information i posted.
[RestKit Installation Submodule Method](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule)